# How can I solve those Qt errors

Tags: c++, qt

When trying to run a simple `Qt program`, I get the following erros: (How can I solve them?)

```
In function `WinMain@16': c:/Qt/2010.05/qt/lib/libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o)

error: undefined reference to _Unwind_Resume:
    C:\qt-greenhouse\Trolltech\Code_less_create_more\
    Trolltech\Code_less_create_more\Troll\4.6\qt\src\winmain/qtmain_win.cpp:93

error: undefined reference to _Unwind_Resume':
    C:\qt-greenhouse\Trolltech\Code_less_create_more\
    Trolltech\Code_less_create_more\Troll\4.6\qt\src\winmain/qtmain_win.cpp:135

error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your libraries aren't linking. Try providing the proper paths to your libraries.

Comment: Judging by your recent questions, your QT environment is not configured correctly. A quick search with a popular search engine found me [this document](http://qtnode.net/wiki/Qt4_with_Visual_Studio), perhaps it will work with your version of Qt...

Comment: Looks like you might have two version of Qt ... I'd probably reinstall

Comment: @AJG85, this message doesn't imply he has two versions of Qt.  Those paths, c:\Qt-greenhouse\... , are the location where Qt was built on the machine in Nokia which compiled the Qt packages.  That is embedded into some of the binaries.

Comment: @DumbCoder. How can I do that?

Comment: @AJG85. I did reinstall, but the same thing

Comment: @user The install should setup environment variables for you as well as putting QT directories in the path variable so things get found. Check your project settings and .pro file in QTCreator ... try building/running one of the demos.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may be either (1) using the incorrect Qt version, or (2) using the incorrect MinGW version.

Did you install just Qt Creator, or the entire Qt SDK?  If you installed only Creator, note that the Qt which comes with it is intended only for Creator itself to use - not for you to build applications with.

If you installed the entire SDK, it should have installed one Qt for you to use, and another Qt for Creator's internal use.  Make sure you're using the correct one.

Comment: I installed the SDK, and using `Qt Creator` that is part of the SDK

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was with the `MinGW` version. I downloaded that latest version of `Qt SDK` that contained `MinGW 4.4` and it worked.